# Why are the XSL functions `ends-with` and `matches` both throwing an error?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming some XML, renaming each element named `alt-title` to `Running_Head`, provided that the attribute `alt-title-type` is equal to "running-head".

---

So, the below code is using the line `<xsl:when test="starts-with(@alt-title-type, 'running-head')">` which is working fine. However, when I change this to either of these:

- `<xsl:when test="ends-with(@alt-title-type, 'running-head')">`
- `<xsl:when test="matches(@alt-title-type, 'running-head')">`

...this error is thrown:

> Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]:
>   xmlXPathCompiledEval: 2 objects left on the stack.

So, it seems that the function `starts-with` is working, where `ends-with` and `matches` are not.

---

Here is my XSL, using `starts-with`, that seems to be working properly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <!-- Running_Head -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="starts-with(@alt-title-type, 'running-head')">
                <xsl:element name="Running_Head">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> <!-- end of Running_Head -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and here is the XML being transformed:

```
<root-node>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="running-head">
        This is working
    </alt-title>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="asdfng-head">
        asdfasdf
    </alt-title>
    <alt-title>
        asdfasdf
    </alt-title>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="running-head">
        This is also working
    </alt-title>
</root-node>
```

I am testing this at http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php, and http://www.xsltcake.com/.

Comment: Please post the erroneous code. That some other code works may be of interest, but is often not relevant in a solution.

Comment: Using the same XML as above, then replace in the XSL the "starts-with" in `<xsl:when test="starts-with(@alt-title-type, 'running-head')">` to either `ends-with` or `matches`.

Comment: Yeah, sure - that's what I did to reproduce the exception. But you make it easier for answerers if you post the problematic code in the first place without the need to change anything. Also, you can avoid the silly questions where it turns out a typo was at fault (like if you had typed `ends-wiith` and didn't notice it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people have pointed out, most XPath 2.0 functions (such as `matches()` and `ends-with()`) are not supported by an XSLT 1.0 processor.

**Moreover, these functions aren't needed at all in a transformation that implements the current requirements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="alt-title[@alt-title-type='running-head']">
  <Running_Head>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </Running_Head>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root-node>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="running-head">
      This is working
  </alt-title>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="asdfng-head">
     asdfasdf
  </alt-title>
    <alt-title>
     asdfasdf
  </alt-title>
    <alt-title alt-title-type="running-head">
     This is also working
  </alt-title>
</root-node>
```

**the wanted, correct reault is produced:**

```
<root-node>
   <Running_Head alt-title-type="running-head">
      This is working
  </Running_Head>
   <alt-title alt-title-type="asdfng-head">
     asdfasdf
  </alt-title>
   <alt-title>
     asdfasdf
  </alt-title>
   <Running_Head alt-title-type="running-head">
     This is also working
  </Running_Head>
</root-node>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of templates, match patterns and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre! This is a clear and simple solution, and thanks for the link as well -- I will study this. ;) Also, could you please clarify the usage of `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in this XSL? Does this strip the space between lines, and not the white-spaces in the String itself?

Comment: @IanCampbell: You are welcome. `xsl:strip-space elements="*" instructs the XML parser to discard all whitespace-only text nodes of the source XML documents. This doesn't touch at all any non-whitespace-only text node.

Comment: How can I use this: `<xsl:for-each select="root/*[matches(name(.), 'grp')]">` in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 3):

Only XPath 2.0 has the `matches` and `ends-with` functions.

In XPath 1.0, `ends-with` must be written

```
$suffix = substring($target, string-length($target) - string-length($suffix) + 1)
```

It has no regular expression functionality, but maybe

contains($target, $substring)

is what you want if you are using no regular expression metacharacters

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification @Borodin! So, would this be correct syntax? -- `<xsl:when test="substring(@alt-title-type, string-length(@alt-title-type) - string-length('running-head') + 1)">`

Comment: `<xsl:when test="'running-head' = substring(@alt-title-type, string-length(@alt-title-type) - string-length('running-head') + 1)">` I think. It looks right! You may want to put `'running-head'` into a variable so that you can't mistype it.

Comment: What it does is to take a substring off the end of the target string equal in length to the match, and then compares to see if it's equal to the match.

Comment: Your last statement here works perfectly, thanks again Borodin! I think there is a minimal chance that this attribute would exceed "running-head" (for example:  `running-head-asdf`), but it seemed a good idea to *exactly* specify the attribute name as it should be, as your example does.

Comment: If you prefer you could code it as `<xsl:when test="substring(@alt-title-type, string-length(@alt-title-type) - 11)">` as the length of `'running-head'` is constant. But the code becomes less self-explanatory

Comment: How can I use this: `<xsl:for-each select="root/*[matches(name(.), 'grp')]">` in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

You declare your template as XSLT 1.0, but you're using the 2.0 functions `ends-with` and `matches`. Use an XSL 2.0 processor (or [work around the missing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712961/35070)), and declare your document as XSLT 2.0.

Note that the error you get is an internal error of the XSL processor used by these services (it looks like they do not correctly handle undefined functions).

Comment: Simplified the answer. I'd be grateful if the downvoter could point out what's wrong with it.

Comment: One minor criticism (but I'm not the downvoter) is that setting version="2.0" is not essential, so long as you run with a 2.0 processor.